# How to highlight columns in excel that don't meet desired condition using R

Tags: r, openxlsx

I hope that the title was descriptive enough or at least made sense. So I know you can do all this data manipulation in R but not all my collages know how to use R so I wanted to make some excel files for them to look at.

So I saw that there were some packages out there that can help me with that I am attempting to do but I'm not sure how to use them in the specific way I am imagining.

So I have a dataset that looks something like this but in a much large scale. So each column has a title and will either have "yes" or a blank in each cell. What I want to do is high light the entire column if it is blank. So in the small example 
I made, I would ideally have samples 1 & 2 highlighted. Is this something that could possibly be done in R and then exported into an excel document?

```
sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4
yes             yes
yes 
yes 
yes             yes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your that the blanks are NA in R the following lines of code can help. Comments in code for explanations where needed.

```
library(openxlsx)

# find empty columns
columns_to_format <- which(sapply(df1, function(x) length(x) == sum(is.na(x)) ))
rows <- nrow(df1) + 1


wb <- createWorkbook()

# create style used for high lighting empty columns
highlight_cells <- createStyle(fgFill = "yellow")

# Add worksheet
addWorksheet(wb, "example")
writeData(wb, "example", x = df1)

# loop over columns to high light
for(i in seq_along(columns_to_format)) {
  addStyle(wb, "example", style = highlight_cells, rows = 2:rows, cols = columns_to_format[i])
}

saveWorkbook(wb, "Example.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

[image]

data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(sample1 = c("yes", "yes", "yes", "yes"), sample2 = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), sample3 = c("yes", 
NA, NA, "yes"), sample4 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```